# How to print dynamic span class value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span class value which comes dynamically.`{{$school->name}}` .The problem is i can see the value on alert when i click on it.But not every time. What could be the optimal solution..can anyone please suggest?

```
  <div class="dropdown_wrapper">
       @foreach($schools as $school)
          <li class="school" id="school1">
              <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span>
              <span class="school_title">{{$school->name}}</span>
          </li>
       @endforeach
    </div>



 $(".school_title").on("click", function (argument) {
     var school = $(this).html();
        alert(school);
 });
```

Comment: the value in the span i.e `$school->name` is coming every time or it is coming only sometimes?

Comment: every time..it shows through dropdown.

Comment: but on clicking the dropdown it is not alerting the value every time..... right?

Comment: yes..that's the problem

Comment: can you check by applying a small timeout with your jquery function...sometimes such errors are caused due to angular-jquery combination....for such logic requiring jquery in angular it is always better to use a directive instead of jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your problem You are looking for this kind of stuff:-

```
 <div class="dropdown_wrapper">
   @foreach($schools as $key => $school)
      <li class="school" id="school1">
          <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span>
          <span id="{{$key}}" class="school_title">{{$school->name}}</span>
      </li>
   @endforeach
</div>



$(".school_title").on("click", function () {
   var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    var school = $("#"+getid).html();
    alert(school);
});
```

Hope it helps!